# Що означає русинською "Шитким лучки"?

Tags: значення-слів, діалекти, займенники, лемківський-діалект

Слова з народної пісні у виконанні Христини Соловій "Сідит пташок". Там є такий діалог:

> *(Хлопець)*
> Мила, мила, што зробила
> Же ти мене зводила
> **Шитким лучки ти покосив**
> Гей, а ти з другим ходила
> *(Дівчина)*
> А я з другим не ходила, гей
> Лем, я тебе чекала
> До ти лучки, штось покосив
> Гей, я ти ласком платила

Тут найскладніше це слово "шитким". Воно схоже на польске "vszystkym" тобто "усім". Але за змістом не підходить ("ти покосив" - тобто "тобі", а не усім).

Comment: Чому думаєте, що *ти* тут *тобі*, а не *ти*? А так, тут _шитким_ це *усі/м*, а _лучки_, це зменшене _лука_ «рівна місцевість, вкрита травою, луг; вигин річки або берега моря; [місце біля хати, де косять траву О; сінокісна низина у вигині річки Ч]».

Comment: @Sútnôstj тут із контексту зрозуміло. *"Мила, мила што зробила, же ти мене зводила"* - це явно слова чоловіка і далі він ж і продовжує *"шитким лучки ти покосив"*, тобто *[я] покосив тобі усі(?) луки*. Він покосив луки саме для неї,  а не "усім", хоч вона, невдячна, *"з другим ходила"*. І далі йому дівчина відповідає, що *за ті лучки, що [ти] покосив, я відповідала ласкою*. Це підтверджує, що він працював саме заради неї.

Comment: Трактую вірш інакше, спробую пояснити, на що скажіть, чи згідні [повністю чи частково], чи взагалі зрозуміли про що я. Він покосив усім лучки, на котрі вона водила. І потім жаліє ся, що водила й ішного. Вона відказує, що з іншим не ходила, а чекала на одній лучці, котру він косив і де платила ласкою.

Comment: @Sútnôstj цікава версія. Мені тут здається, що ключове слово *зводила* вжито у переносному значенні, тобто *підвела*